# How to generate a correct JWT without using Firebase

Tags: php, jwt, docusignapi

I am trying to generate a JWT for the DocuSign Embed API and I can't seem to figure out the private/public key part.

When I generate the JWT, the signature part is very short. Pasting it in jwt.io, it turns out both the header and payload are correct, but the signature part is wrong (and way too short when I compare it to what I get when I copy paste my public and rsa private keys.

Here is the relevant code:

```
$args = [
    'envelope_id' => $_GET['envelope_id'], 
    'ds_return_url' => 'https://www.returnurl.be',
    'starting_view' => 'envelope',
    'base_path' => 'https://baseurl.be'
];

$args['integration_key'] = 'abc123'; 
if(isset($_GET['user_id'])) {
    $args['user_id'] = $_GET['user_id'];
}

//generate jwt: 
$headers = array('alg'=>'RS256','typ'=>'JWT');
$payload = array(
    'iss'=>$args['integration_key'],
    'sub'=>$args['user_id'], 
    'aud'=>'account-d.docusign.com', //prod: account.docusign.com 
    'iat'=>time(), 
    'exp'=>(time() + 6000),
    'scope'=>'signature impersonation'
);
$secret = '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAj...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----';

$jwt = generate_jwt($headers, $payload, $secret);
echo $jwt;

function generate_jwt($headers, $payload, $secret = 'secret') {
    $headers_encoded = base64url_encode(json_encode($headers));
    
    $payload_encoded = base64url_encode(json_encode($payload));
    
    $signature = hash_hmac('SHA256', "$headers_encoded.$payload_encoded", $secret, true);
    $signature_encoded = base64url_encode($signature);
    
    $jwt = "$headers_encoded.$payload_encoded.$signature_encoded";
    
    return $jwt;
}
function base64url_encode($str) {
    return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($str), '+/', '-_'), '=');
}
```

Comment: Why not use the PHP SDK? it's a packigst package that makes all this much easier. I highly recommend you consider this option

Comment: you have RSA private key, but you're not using RSA256 as a signing algorithm. Your signature algorithm is HMAC-SHA256 (HS256). I don't know what you actually need, but I recommend to use a [JWT library](https://jwt.io/libraries?language=PHP) instead of writing your own code to create a token.

Comment: We’re supposed to use the up arrow for comments (which I did), but I can’t stress enough to use a library for this. No shortcuts, no “I don’t need that feature” or “it doesn’t apply to me”.